# why FFT results in high frequency range are not correct?

Tags: matlab, fft

I am doing FFT with matlab.the time period i am doing the fft on it is 1 second and it consist of 50000 equlay spaces samples. I want to test the FFT results. so I have given an input as below (wave) which is a complex of sinosuidal waves (and I have samples it by sampling frequency of 50 KHZ)and I expect to have the frequency magnitude results as I have given in the input. the results are ok for low frequency ranges but for the higher frequency (5752 Hz and 7993 Hz) results are 5.87 and 6.7 respectively (instead of 6 and ). what Is the origin of this big mistake ? how can I improve my results ?!

Here is the code:

```
t = 0:1/50000:1;

wave = 100*sin(2*pi*50*t)+1*sin (2*pi*123*t)+2*sin (2*pi*203*t)+3*sin(2*pi*223*t)+4*sin(2*pi*331*t)+5*sin(2*pi*2812*t)+6*sin(2*pi*5752*t)+7*sin(2*pi*7993*t);

SPEC = fft(wave);

L = size(SPEC,2);
x= (0:L/2-1);
Half_SPEC = abs(SPEC(1:L/2))/(L/2);  %% removing the mirror side and ranging the domain 

plot(x,Half_SPEC);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the results"?

Comment: Note also that you have 50001 samples here.

Comment: Hi Oli , by "the results"I mean the magnitude of FFT in the frequencies specified by the time domain signal . for example the magnitude for frequncy of 50 hz should be 100 and it is , but for higher frequencies it is not exactly as what I have denoted in my time domain signal and it causes a remarkable error in my caculations!

Comment: This is spectral leakage - an inherent property of the discrete FT of finite-length sequences.

Comment: On R2014a, it looks like the magnitudes line up: 
plot([50 123 203 223 331 2812 5752 7993],[100 1 2 3 4 5 6 7],'xr')

Comment: thans for the help. I got the problem .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Oli Charlesworth has pointed out, you are taking the FFT of 50001 points, which means that the frequency spacing is 1/50001.

Typically the FFT will give you the exact magnitude of your sinusoid only if its frequency is an exact multiple of the frequency spacing. Otherwise, the energy will be spread over multiple FFT bins in a process called [spectral leakage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function).
You may confirm this by changing the number of samples such that the frequency of your sinusoids are a multiple of the frequency spacing:

```
t = 0:1/50000:1-1/50000;
```

[Windowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function) the input signal can also help control the amount of leakage.

Comment: Thanks for extra explanation I got it.